Limit of stochastically continuous process
Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of random variable taking values in $\mathbb{D}[0,1]$, the space of cadlag function equipped with Skorokhod topology, so that each $X_n$ can be viewed as a cadlag stochastic process.
We assume that $X_n$ is stochastically continuous, that is, for each $t$, $X_n(s)\rightarrow X_n(t)$ in probability as $s\rightarrow t$.
Assume that $X_n\rightarrow X$ in $\mathbb{D}[0,1]$, where $X$ is another cadlag stochastic process. I want to find the condition when $X$ is also a stochastically continuous process.
